# Bookshelf JS Messing With Tablename

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, knex.js, bookshelf.js

**Introduction**

I'm trying to make a simple query on a table in mssql 2019 using the bookshelf.js and knex.js libraries. The table is part of a schema.

**Issue Description**

I get a sql error in my sqlserver because either bookshelf.js or knex.js has messed with my schema by modifying my tablename:
I would like to know if there's a way to keep my table name as is or to define my schema as its own field.

**Steps to reproduce issue**

I have a user model defined with bookshelf.js like this:

```
const User = bookshelf.model('User', {
    tableName: '[thanos.User]'
});
```

Using bookshelf.js's count() function:

```
User.count().then((count) => {
    console.log('number of users:', count)
})
```

**Expected behaviour**

```
sql: select count(*) as [count] from [thanos.User]
```

**Actual behaviour**

```
sql: select count(*) as [count] from [thanos].[User]
```

Comment: There's the `withSchema` option that you can use, but I have no idea if it works with MSSQL: https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/pull/1638

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the frameworks, but from what you are seeing my guess would be that the `[` and `]` in your model definition are possibly being removed.

Do they need to be escaped in this framework - e.g. something like `tablename: '[[thanos.user]' ?

Comment: I've tried '[[thanos.user]]' and '\\[thanos.user\\]', as well, there is an 'escape' function defined in the api docs https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-instance-escape, but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf suggests that it is only supported with MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite3.
I'm not familiar enough with to understand how they deal with schemas, but it may be different than SQL Server does which could be the root of your issue?